# Print Variable To Input Field Element

Tags: javascript

Hi I have this input and I am wondering how I can print a value to it based on it's ID?

```
<input name="field[34]" id="field34" class="input-text required-entry validate-field-hint-34 webforms-fields-hint" style="" value="E.g: NX15 NAM" onfocus="if (this.value == 'E.g: NX15 NAM') {this.value = ''; $(this).removeClassName('webforms-fields-hint');}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E.g: NX15 NAM'; $(this).addClassName('webforms-fields-hint');}" type="text">
```

I have this script which takes the value of the URL and turns it into a variable. I now want to print this variable to the input field.

```
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
}();
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very simple, just substitute the below placeholder values with your actual values.

```
document.getElementById("yourElementId").value = yourVariableName;
```

Make sure you `DOM` is loaded before trying this.

**Edit 1**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("yourElementId").value = yourVariableName;
}, false);
```

Comment: Hi so I have tried this although I am just getting this: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null. using the following block of code: document.getElementById("field34").value = QueryString;

Comment: @user3786396 Make sure you DOM is loaded before trying this.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit of noob at JavaScript, can you show me an example that would wait until the DOM loads before this script fires? Sorry for asking so much I am just a little confused. Thanks, Nick

Comment: Read my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036024/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-dom-of-null/32036128#32036128

Comment: Okay so I've added my code to the addEventListener and I am now getting this error haha: ReferenceError: yourCallbackFunction is not defined. Any idea why this might now be happening?

Comment: @user3786396 please learn how to use JavaScript. yourCallbackFunction is not defined. It was a placeholder function.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, here we go

```
$('.inputClassName').val(varName);
```

Hope this helps